# Using Explicit Cast in an Extension Method

Tags: c#, casting, extension-methods

I have a weird problem when I'm trying to cast an object via an extension method.  I have a class where I wrap some functionality around an `IPAddress`.

```
// Dumbed down version of class
public sealed class PrefixLengthIPAddress
{
    public static explicit operator IPAddress(PrefixLengthIPAddress address)
    {
        return (address != null) ? address._address : null;
    }

    public PrefixLengthIPAddress(IPAddress address)
    {
        _address = address;
        _length = address.GetLength();
    }

    private readonly ushort _length;
    private readonly IPAddress _address;
}
```

I don't like the look of all the parenthesis to extract the `IPAddress` out of the object:

```
var family = ((IPAddress)prefixLengthAddress).AddressFamily;
```

I'd rather be able to do something like this:

```
var family = prefixLengthAddress.CastAs<IPAddress>().AddressFamily;
```

In order to do this I wrote the following Extension Method:

```
public static T CastAs<T>(this object value) where T : class
{
    return (T)value;
}
```

Unfortunately with this I'm getting an `InvalidCastException`:

```
var family = ((IPAddress)prefixLengthAddress).AddressFamily;         // Works
var family = prefixLengthAddress.CastAs<IPAddress>().AddressFamily;  // InvalidCastException
```

I understand that in this particular case I could simply expose the `IPAddress` with a getter, but we also have more complex explicit casts that I would like to do this with.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Chris Sinclair's comment on using `dynamic` I have updated the extension method to look like:

```
public static T CastAs<T>(this object value)
{
    return (T)((dynamic)value);
}
```

There is some overhead with using `dynamic`, but it is more than fast enough for my needs.  It also seems to work with all the basic type casting I've tried.

Comment: Well, `PrefixLengthIPAddress` has no relation in the type hierarchy to `IPAddress`, which is the ultimate source of the problem. What is the other situation you would use this casting code for? Trying to arbitrarily force an instance of type A to an instance of type B is bound for failure. Additionally, the Generic is actually unbounded; so `T` could be an `string`, and no operator overloading can occur. I suspect even bounding to `IPAddress` for `T` would not lead to the behavior you expect, and even if it did, your extension is useless otherwise.

Comment: I just like the look of the extension method better.  If I tried to cast my object as a string I'd expect it to throw an InvalidCastException either way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first sample you are accessing the user defined conversion.  This is only available when the cast operator knows the type of the input is `PrefixLengthAddress`.  In the generic code the compiler only knows the type `object` and `T`.  There is no way it can access the conversion defined on `PrefixLengthAddress` in this scenario.

In this scenario what you're doing is much closer to mapping vs. casting since it's actually creating a new value.  In terms of LINQ you would want to use `Select` vs. `Cast`.

Comment: The exception message thrown inside the extension method is "Unable to cast object of type 'PrefixLengthIPAddress' to type 'System.Net.IPAddress'".  So how does it not know the type in this case?

Comment: @lumberjack4 user defined conversions are only used by the language compiler (in this case C#).  In order to be used the types must be known at compile time.  What your seeing is the runtime saying there is no inheritance relationship between 2 types.  The runtime won't consider user defined conversions

Comment: How does the Linq `Enumerable.CastIterator<T>` work then?  When I look at that code it looks almost identical to mine:

    private static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source)
    {
      foreach (object obj in source)
        yield return (TResult) obj;
    }

Comment: @lumberjack4 it works the same way and it would also fail this particular cast.  It can't work with user defined conversions

Comment: @lumberjack4 Does it work? If the `source` has objects that are not _castable_, then it should throw the exception. `explicit operators` are (mostly) just syntactic sugar. They can't be applied from type `object` to type `T`. What _might_ be possible is to first cast to `dynamic`: `return (T)(dynamic)value;` but this would incur runtime costs as the explicit conversions are resolved at runtime. I've seen it used something like this before (but off the top of my head, I'm not _positive_ it's this _exact_ scenario)

Comment: @Chris using `dynamic` makes it work.  I'll have to profile the overhead tomorrow to see how costly it is.